# How to use Delayed::Job in an after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, delayed-job

I want to run the method `process_images` asynchronously `after_save` with `Delayed::Job`. However, when I try:

```
after_save lambda { send_later(:process_images) }
```

I get a `NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!`. (`self.send_later(:process_images)` work either)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work... I do remember using it a while back before switching to Delayed::Job.enqueue instead:

```
after_save do |image|
  image.send_later(:process_images)
end
```

You could also try:

```
after_save :cue_process_images

def cue_process_images
  send_later(:process_images)
end
```

I'm currently using something similar to the later, using paperclip and it works fine.